# Did later literary analysis agree with Mark Twain's criticism of J.F. Cooper?

Tags: mark-twain, james-fenimore-cooper

This [excellent answer by @CHEESE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/190/what-specific-criticisms-did-mark-twain-make-against-jane-austens-books) linked to a Mark Twain's "[Fenimore Cooper's Literary Offenses](http://twain.lib.virginia.edu/projects/rissetto/offense.html)".

**SPOILER ALERT:** That essay is extremely critical of Cooper's work.

Did later literary analysis largely agree with Mark Twain's criticism of Cooper or largely contradict it?

Comment: Might also be worth asking if "later literary analysis" agrees with Twain's criticism of Jane Austin.

Comment: To the closevoter: this isn't opinion based. It's basically "Did anybody say this about Cooper's work". Nothing opinion-based there.

Comment: Could you edit this question to make it more self-contained, by adding either a summary of or some quotes from Mark Twain's article?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - summary: "JFC's writing sucks. Here's a long list of reasons".  I'm not sure I can condense the reasons, to be honest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[It appears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenimore_Cooper's_Literary_Offenses#Reception) that most later critics think that Twain's criticism was unfair, and possibly intended as humor.

John McWilliams writes:

> Hilarious though Twain's essay is, it is valid only within its own
>   narrow and sometimes misapplied criteria.<sup>1</sup>

Some other sources cited by Wikipedia appear to claim that the essay was not intended as a criticism at all, but as humor, because Twain's criticisms are not realistic. In this essay, Twain is "Impos[ing] the standards of Realism on Romance," which is humorously incongruous.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> "[Fenimore Cooper's Literary Offenses (Introduction)](http://xroads.virginia.edu/~hyper/HNS/Indians/critic.html)". *Twain's Indians*. University of Virginia.
<sup>2</sup> Andriano, Joeseph. *The Routledge Encyclopedia of Mark Twain* p. 287 (1993)